# Running a separate function alongside a loop in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi

I am trying to display RSS data on an LED sign using a Raspberry PI. I've based my code on a script that  I found for the sign when I first bought it. It's a simple script that allows you to send a message and a colour to the sign and it will scroll across until a keyboard interrupt.

```
sudo python scroll "Hello World" 1 #red
sudo python scroll "Hello World" 2 #green
sudo python scroll "Hello World" 3 #red and green (orange)
```

The difference between this script and the one that I am working on is that all the all the data is processed before the loop and then the showmatrix() function is used to show the string on the screen and the shiftmatrix() function is used to scroll the image across.

In order to constantly download the RSS data I have put the following code inside the loop:

```
#grab emails
newmails = int(feedparser.parse("https://" + USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD +"@mail.google.com/gmail/feed/atom")["feed"]["fullcount"])

textinput =  "You have " + str(newmails) + " new emails"

# append extra characters to text input to allow for wrap-around
textinput+="  ::  "
```

I then use the same functions as before to display this data on the sign:

```
# Continually output to the display until Ctrl-C
    #

# loop around each column in the dotarray
for col in range(len(dotarray[0])):
    for row in range(8):
        # copy the current dotarray column values to the first column in the matrix
        matrix[row][0]=(dotarray[row][col])
    # now that we have updated the matrix lets show it
    showmatrix()
    # shift the matrix left ready for the next column
    shiftmatrix()
```

As the RSS data download takes so long (at last a second), the output loop doesn't run for that time and the sign goes blank. Is there a way of running the feedparser function at the same time so there is no delay?

Am I correct in thinking that multithreading is the way forward? I had a look into couroutines but that got me nowhere.

Comment: You should take a look at `os.fork`. Forking processes is a very simple way to do some multitasking stuff. Otherwise, multithreading is the way of course.

Comment: Multithreading isn't a good idea in python, because of [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) instead.

Comment: @semptic, that's not entirely true. Multithreading still has its uses, especially with GUIs. Because of the GIL, threads will be executed in a serial fashion, but to us humans it might appear as parallel execution because every 100 bytecode operations (default), a different thread can become active. For this particular case, I believe threading is a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, os.fork(), youcan  make the function run in a different process or the threading module to make it run in another thread.
If the function uses global variables you need to use the threading module and make it run in another thread and if not i'd suggest to do it anyway, less resource wasteful (assuming the function doesnt allocate alot of memory or otherwise uses alot of resources), you code should look something like this:

```
class displayThread(threading.Thread)
    *init function if you need to pass info to the tread, otherwise dont write one but if you do
     make sure to call Thread.__init__() first in your function*
    def run():  //Overrides the run function
        *display what you want on the display*

class downloadThread(threading.Thread)
    *init function if you need to pass info to the tread, otherwise dont write one but if you do
     make sure to call Thread.__init__() first in your function*
    def run():  //Overrides the run function
        *download what you want*
```

and your main script should look like:

```
thread1 = displayThread
thread2 = downloadThread
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread2.join()   //waits for download to finish while the display in being updated by the other thread
```

and if you want to stop the display thread (assuming it goes on forever) you will have to add something like:

```
os.kill(thread1.getpid(), signal.SIGKILL)
```

after the .join() and do what you want with the downloaded info.

The multi process version is very similar and you should be able to understand how to make it from my example and the os.fork() docs, if you are having trouble with it - let me know and i'll edit this.